# Why opencv's triangulatePoints return false results?

Tags: c++, opencv, triangulation, 3d-reconstruction

I'm working on opencv's triangulatepoints and have some problems. Here is my work:

**STEP 1.**
I generate seven 3D points by function generate3DPoints()

[0.5, 0.5, -0.5]

[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

[-0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

[-0.5, 0.5, -0.5]

[0.5, -0.5, -0.5]

[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5]

[-0.5, -0.5, 0.5]

**STEP 2.**
Then I project them to two images by opencv's function projectPoints(), and save 2D points in vector leftImagePoints and righttImagePoints respectively.

Image point: [0.5, 0.5, -0.5] Projected to [736.754, 618.17]

Image point: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5] Projected to [731.375, 611.951]

Image point: [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5] Projected to [688.719, 612.961]

Image point: [-0.5, 0.5, -0.5] Projected to [692.913, 619.172]

Image point: [0.5, -0.5, -0.5] Projected to [737.767, 573.217]

Image point: [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5] Projected to [693.936, 574.331]

Image point: [-0.5, -0.5, 0.5] Projected to [689.71, 569.285]

---

Image point: [0.5, 0.5, -0.5] Projected to [702.397, -121.563]

Image point: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5] Projected to [696.125, -93.1121]

Image point: [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5] Projected to [632.271, -90.1316]

Image point: [-0.5, 0.5, -0.5] Projected to [634.829, -116.987]

Image point: [0.5, -0.5, -0.5] Projected to [715.505, -230.592]

Image point: [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5] Projected to [642.35, -219.8]

Image point: [-0.5, -0.5, 0.5] Projected to [638.094, -180.103]

**STEP 3.**
After that, I use opencv's function triangulatePoints to get homo-coordinates and convert them to ordinary 3D coordinate.

reconstruction result

10.43599, 7.2594047, -33.088718;

11.009606, 7.6683388, -33.098804;

10.033145, 7.6832604, -33.375408;

9.5006475, 7.2904119, -33.379032;

9.5954504, 5.7358074, -32.76096;

8.7637157, 5.8084483, -33.068729;

9.3709002, 6.2525721, -33.122173

Now you can see: the original 3D points I generate by myself are different  from the result after projection and reconstruction. I can not find the problem, I hope you can help me~
THANKS!

here is my code(by opencv 2.4.9)

```html
// testVirtualData.cpp : 
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


vector<Point3f> generate3DPoints()
{
 vector<Point3f> pointsXYZ; // save 7 points

 double x, y, z;
 
 x = 0.5; y = 0.5; z = -0.5;
 pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3f(x, y, z));

 x = 0.5; y = 0.5; z = 0.5;
 pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3f(x, y, z));

 x = -0.5; y = 0.5; z = 0.5;
 pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3f(x, y, z));

 x = -0.5; y = 0.5; z = -0.5;
 pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3f(x, y, z));

 x = 0.5; y = -0.5; z = -0.5;
 pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3f(x, y, z));

 x = -0.5; y = -0.5; z = -0.5;
 pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3f(x, y, z));

 x = -0.5; y = -0.5; z = 0.5;
 pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3f(x, y, z));

 for (int i = 0; i < pointsXYZ.size(); i++)
 {
  cout << pointsXYZ[i] << endl;
 }
 
 return pointsXYZ;
}


vector<Point3f> triangulateInOpenCV(Matx34d leftPMat, Matx34d rightPMat, vector<Point2f> leftPtsxy, vector<Point2f> rightPtsxy)
{
 Mat corrPtsXYZHomo(4, leftPtsxy.size(), CV_64FC1);
 triangulatePoints(leftPMat, rightPMat, leftPtsxy, rightPtsxy, corrPtsXYZHomo);

 cout << "reconsturction result 3D points in homo-coordinate" << endl;
 cout << corrPtsXYZHomo << endl;

 vector<Point3f> corrPtsXYZ;
 
 for (int i = 0; i < corrPtsXYZHomo.cols; i++)  
 {
  float x = corrPtsXYZHomo.at<float>(0, i) / corrPtsXYZHomo.at<float>(3, i);
  float y = corrPtsXYZHomo.at<float>(1, i) / corrPtsXYZHomo.at<float>(3, i);
  float z = corrPtsXYZHomo.at<float>(2, i) / corrPtsXYZHomo.at<float>(3, i);
  corrPtsXYZ.push_back(Point3f(x, y, z));
  int t = 1;
 }

 return corrPtsXYZ;
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 vector<Point3f> objectPoints = generate3DPoints();  //generate by myself
 vector<Point2f> rightImagePoints; // save project 
 vector<Point2f> leftImagePoints; // save project result


 // 1. intrinsic Matrix
 Mat intrisicMat(3, 3, DataType<double>::type);  
 intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 0) = 1.6415318549788924e+003;
 intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
 intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 0) = 0;

 intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 1) = 0;
 intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 1) = 1.7067753507885654e+003;
 intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 1) = 0;

 intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 2) = 5.3262822453148601e+002;
 intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 2) = 3.8095355839052968e+002;
 intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 2) = 1;


 // 2.3. R T
 // left
 double leftRMatArray[] =
 {
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
 };
 Mat leftRMat = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1, leftRMatArray); //Rotation Matrix
 Mat leftRVec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type); // Rotation vector
 Rodrigues(leftRMat, leftRVec);

 Mat leftTVec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type); // Translation vector
 leftTVec.at<double>(0) = 4.1158489381208221e+000;
 leftTVec.at<double>(1) = 4.6847683212704716e+000;
 leftTVec.at<double>(2) = 3.6169795190294256e+001;
 //leftTVec.at<double>(0) = 0;
 //leftTVec.at<double>(1) = 0;
 //leftTVec.at<double>(2) = 0;

 // right
 Mat rightRVec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type); // Rotation vector
 rightRVec.at<double>(0) = -3.9277902400761393e-002;
 rightRVec.at<double>(1) = 3.7803824407602084e-002;
 rightRVec.at<double>(2) = 2.6445674487856268e-002;


 Mat rightRMat; // Rotation Matrix
 Rodrigues(rightRVec, rightRMat);

 Mat rightTVec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type); // Translation vector
 rightTVec.at<double>(0) = 2.1158489381208221e+000;
 rightTVec.at<double>(1) = -7.6847683212704716e+000;
 rightTVec.at<double>(2) = 2.6169795190294256e+001;



 // 4. distortion
 Mat distCoeffs(5, 1, DataType<double>::type);   // Distortion vector
 distCoeffs.at<double>(0) = -7.9134632415085826e-001;
 distCoeffs.at<double>(1) = 1.5623584435644169e+000;
 distCoeffs.at<double>(2) = -3.3916502741726508e-002;
 distCoeffs.at<double>(3) = -1.3921577146136694e-002;
 distCoeffs.at<double>(4) = 1.1430734623697941e+002;

 cout << "Intrisic matrix: " << intrisicMat << endl << endl;
 cout << "Distortion coef: " << distCoeffs << endl << endl;
 cout << "left Rotation vector: " << leftRVec << endl << endl;
 cout << "left Translation vector: " << leftTVec << endl << endl;
 cout << "right Rotation vector: " << rightRVec << endl << endl;
 cout << "right Translation vector: " << rightTVec << endl << endl;

 // project
 // left
 projectPoints(objectPoints, leftRVec, leftTVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, leftImagePoints);
 
 // right
 projectPoints(objectPoints, rightRVec, rightTVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, rightImagePoints);

 for (int i = 0; i < leftImagePoints.size(); ++i)
 {
  cout << "Image point: " << objectPoints[i] << " Projected to " << leftImagePoints[i] << endl;
 }
 cout << "------------------" << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < rightImagePoints.size(); ++i)
 {
  cout << "Image point: " << objectPoints[i] << " Projected to " << rightImagePoints[i] << endl;
 }

 //triangulate
 double leftPArray[] =
 {
  leftRMat.at<double>(0, 0), leftRMat.at<double>(0, 1), leftRMat.at<double>(0, 2), leftTVec.at<double>(0),
  leftRMat.at<double>(1, 0), leftRMat.at<double>(1, 1), leftRMat.at<double>(1, 2), leftTVec.at<double>(1),
  leftRMat.at<double>(2, 0), leftRMat.at<double>(2, 1), leftRMat.at<double>(2, 2), leftTVec.at<double>(2)
 };
 Mat leftPMat = Mat(3, 4, CV_64FC1, leftPArray); // left P Matrix

 double rightPArray[] =
 {
  rightRMat.at<double>(0, 0), rightRMat.at<double>(0, 1), rightRMat.at<double>(0, 2), rightTVec.at<double>(0),
  rightRMat.at<double>(1, 0), rightRMat.at<double>(1, 1), rightRMat.at<double>(1, 2), rightTVec.at<double>(1),
  rightRMat.at<double>(2, 0), rightRMat.at<double>(2, 1), rightRMat.at<double>(2, 2), rightTVec.at<double>(2)
 };
 Mat rightPMat = Mat(3, 4, CV_64FC1, rightPArray); // right P Matrix

 vector<Point3f> triangulationResult = triangulateInOpenCV(leftPMat, rightPMat, leftImagePoints, rightImagePoints);
 cout << "reconstruction result" << endl;
 cout << triangulationResult << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didnt work through the whole code... did you correct the lens distortion? triangulatePoints does not use distortion coefficients as input parameters so probably the points must be corrected?

Comment: thanks for your reply~ @Micka   after I set the distortion coefficients as [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], the result change indistinctively.   By the way, I haven't use the distortion coefficients in triangulation, they are optional parameters in function projectPoints().

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of projection matrix is not completely true. Let's ignore the lens distortion to make life easier. If A1 and A2 represent internal parameters of two cameras, P1 = A1*[R1|t1] and P2 = A2 * [R2|t2] represent the projections matrices for left and right cameras. You may also need to modify your code a little bit so it only contains double (or float) values. With these changes I got

```
[ 0.5000000000000006,  0.4999999999999996, -0.4999999999999953;
  0.4999999999999991,  0.5000000000000002,  0.5000000000000033;
 -0.5000000000000008,  0.5000000000000003,  0.5000000000000016;
 -0.4999999999999995,  0.4999999999999996, -0.4999999999999952;
  0.5000000000000002, -0.4999999999999998, -0.4999999999999991;
 -0.4999999999999993, -0.4999999999999998, -0.5000000000000001;
 -0.5000000000000012, -0.5000000000000003,  0.4999999999999947]
```

which is close to input points. And here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


vector<Point3d> generate3DPoints()
{
    vector<Point3d> pointsXYZ; // save 7 points

    double x, y, z;

    x = 0.5; y = 0.5; z = -0.5;
    pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = 0.5; y = 0.5; z = 0.5;
    pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -0.5; y = 0.5; z = 0.5;
    pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -0.5; y = 0.5; z = -0.5;
    pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = 0.5; y = -0.5; z = -0.5;
    pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -0.5; y = -0.5; z = -0.5;
    pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -0.5; y = -0.5; z = 0.5;
    pointsXYZ.push_back(Point3d(x, y, z));

    for (int i = 0; i < pointsXYZ.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << pointsXYZ[i] << endl;
    }

    return pointsXYZ;
}


vector<Point3d> triangulateInOpenCV(Matx34d leftPMat, Matx34d rightPMat, vector<Point2d> leftPtsxy, vector<Point2d> rightPtsxy)
{
    Mat corrPtsXYZHomo(4, leftPtsxy.size(), CV_64FC1);
    triangulatePoints(leftPMat, rightPMat, leftPtsxy, rightPtsxy, corrPtsXYZHomo);

    cout << "reconsturction result 3D points in homo-coordinate" << endl;
    cout << corrPtsXYZHomo << endl;

    vector<Point3d> corrPtsXYZ;

    for (int i = 0; i < corrPtsXYZHomo.cols; i++)
    {
        double x = corrPtsXYZHomo.at<double>(0, i) / corrPtsXYZHomo.at<double>(3, i);
        double y = corrPtsXYZHomo.at<double>(1, i) / corrPtsXYZHomo.at<double>(3, i);
        double z = corrPtsXYZHomo.at<double>(2, i) / corrPtsXYZHomo.at<double>(3, i);
        corrPtsXYZ.push_back(Point3d(x, y, z));
        int t = 1;
    }

    return corrPtsXYZ;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<Point3d> objectPoints = generate3DPoints();  //generate by myself
    vector<Point2d> rightImagePoints; // save project 
    vector<Point2d> leftImagePoints; // save project result


                                     // 1. intrinsic Matrix
    Mat intrisicMat(3, 3, DataType<double>::type);
    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 0) = 1.6415318549788924e+003;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 0) = 0;

    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 1) = 0;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 1) = 1.7067753507885654e+003;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 1) = 0;

    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 2) = 5.3262822453148601e+002;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 2) = 3.8095355839052968e+002;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 2) = 1;


    // 2.3. R T
    // left
    double leftRMatArray[] =
    {
        1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 1
    };
    Mat leftRMat = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1, leftRMatArray); //Rotation Matrix
    Mat leftRVec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type); // Rotation vector
    Rodrigues(leftRMat, leftRVec);

    Mat leftTVec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type); // Translation vector
    leftTVec.at<double>(0) = 4.1158489381208221e+000;
    leftTVec.at<double>(1) = 4.6847683212704716e+000;
    leftTVec.at<double>(2) = 3.6169795190294256e+001;

    // right
    Mat rightRVec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type); // Rotation vector
    rightRVec.at<double>(0) = -3.9277902400761393e-002;
    rightRVec.at<double>(1) = 3.7803824407602084e-002;
    rightRVec.at<double>(2) = 2.6445674487856268e-002;


    Mat rightRMat; // Rotation Matrix
    Rodrigues(rightRVec, rightRMat);

    Mat rightTVec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type); // Translation vector
    rightTVec.at<double>(0) = 2.1158489381208221e+000;
    rightTVec.at<double>(1) = -7.6847683212704716e+000;
    rightTVec.at<double>(2) = 2.6169795190294256e+001;



    // 4. distortion
    Mat distCoeffs(5, 1, DataType<double>::type);   // Distortion vector
    distCoeffs.at<double>(0) = 0;// -7.9134632415085826e-001;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(1) = 0;//1.5623584435644169e+000;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(2) = 0;//-3.3916502741726508e-002;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(3) = 0;//-1.3921577146136694e-002;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(4) = 0;//1.1430734623697941e+002;

    cout << "Intrisic matrix: " << intrisicMat << endl << endl;
    cout << "Distortion coef: " << distCoeffs << endl << endl;
    cout << "left Rotation vector: " << leftRVec << endl << endl;
    cout << "left Translation vector: " << leftTVec << endl << endl;
    cout << "right Rotation vector: " << rightRVec << endl << endl;
    cout << "right Translation vector: " << rightTVec << endl << endl;

    // project
    // left
    projectPoints(objectPoints, leftRVec, leftTVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, leftImagePoints);

    // right
    projectPoints(objectPoints, rightRVec, rightTVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, rightImagePoints);

    for (int i = 0; i < leftImagePoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "Image point: " << objectPoints[i] << " Projected to " << leftImagePoints[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rightImagePoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "Image point: " << objectPoints[i] << " Projected to " << rightImagePoints[i] << endl;
    }

    Mat m1 = intrisicMat * leftRMat;
    Mat t1 = intrisicMat * leftTVec;

    //triangulate
    double leftPArray[] =
    {
        m1.at<double>(0, 0),m1.at<double>(0, 1),m1.at<double>(0, 2), t1.at<double>(0,0),
        m1.at<double>(1, 0),m1.at<double>(1, 1),m1.at<double>(1, 2), t1.at<double>(1,0),
        m1.at<double>(2, 0),m1.at<double>(2, 1),m1.at<double>(2, 2), t1.at<double>(2,0)
    };
    Mat leftPMat = Mat(3, 4, CV_64FC1, leftPArray); // left P Matrix

    Mat m2 = intrisicMat * rightRMat;
    Mat t2 = intrisicMat * rightTVec;
    double rightPArray[] =
    {
        m2.at<double>(0, 0), m2.at<double>(0, 1), m2.at<double>(0, 2), t2.at<double>(0,0),
        m2.at<double>(1, 0), m2.at<double>(1, 1), m2.at<double>(1, 2), t2.at<double>(1,0),
        m2.at<double>(2, 0), m2.at<double>(2, 1), m2.at<double>(2, 2), t2.at<double>(2,0)
    };
    Mat rightPMat = Mat(3, 4, CV_64FC1, rightPArray); // right P Matrix

    vector<Point3d> triangulationResult = triangulateInOpenCV(leftPMat, rightPMat, leftImagePoints, rightImagePoints);
    cout << "reconstruction result" << endl;
    cout << triangulationResult << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```